# uwp scrollviewer viewport - Is there a way to know if the current Control is in viewport and visible to user?

Tags: windows, gridview, uwp

In uwp windows app.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="filesView_Thumbnail">
<Grid><Image /></Grid>.... long list of Grid or GridView with ItemTemplate
</ScrollViewer>
```

When I load long list of Images in scrollViewer, I want to load the images that is visible to User first because loading image takes time.

Is there a way I can fire an event or calculate which Grid or Image control is currently in the current ViewPort and visible to user?

I tried rough calculation with width and height, but it's off when it goes long list. And this method doesn't work when the size of Grid and Image controls varies.

Comment: I think ListView is a better choice for this pattern. ListView already supports virtualization, so only items that are in the view will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As the Raymond Chen said, you could use ListView. When you load a long list of Images, it would be a waste of resources to create the UI for all the images at the same time. So you need to create the UI for images on demand. ListView and GridView (and other standard ItemsControl-derived controls) perform **UI virtualization** for you. In other words, for an items control bound to multiple items collection, when items are close to being scrolled into view (a few pages away), the framework can generate UI for these items and caches them.

**Note that** ListView has the built-in scrollviewer, you don’t need to add scrollviewer for it, otherwise, it will affect the UI virtualization.